# What is the difference between simplewallet, wallet and wallet2?

Tags: wallet

There seems to be 3 variations of wallets in the Monero code.

I could not find "wallet" so I'm unsure it exists, unless wallet2 refers to being a second wallet but not a simple one?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between simplewallet, wallet and wallet2?

simplewallet.[cpp|h] is the source code for the command-line wallet monero-wallet-cli.

wallet2.[cpp|h] is the source code for the core wallet functionality. simplewallet therefore makes heavy use of this.

> There seems to be 3 variations of wallets in the Monero code.

No, there are only two wallets in the source tree. There is the command-line wallet, `monero-wallet-cli`, as detailed above and the wallet RPC server, `monero-wallet-rpc`. Both of these are simply wrappers around the core wallet functionality as implemented in wallet2.

There is also an optional wallet API library that can be built (source in the wallet/api directory) which is designed to allow for a simpler interface to the core wallet code), and there is also some old "light" wallet library code, but consensus seems to be that this is unused by anything and is therefore redundant now.

Comment: Oh so simplewallet is just a cli into wallet2. Why is it called Wallet2? Is there a Wallet(1)?

Comment: "Oh so simplewallet is just a cli into wallet2" <- correct.

Comment: "Why is it called Wallet2? Is there a Wallet(1)?" <- Why the original author called it wallet2 I can not answer. Supposedly to distinguish it as an implementation rather then a concrete "wallet" implementation.